# Django allauth Social application accessing extra data

Tags: django, django-allauth

[I have added Google authentication for my Django web application using allauth package. I want to access the extra data(shown in field 4(Extra data) of social account users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al5da.png)

I have tried this but, I do not import SocialAccount(I dont know to which module does it belongs to).
`data=SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user).extra_data`
Please let me know which module should I import to use **SocialAccount** or tell me other way how can I access extra data.

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
```

Now, use the SocialAccount model like any other Django model

```
SocialAccount.objects.all()
```